# Var-arg method accepting only primitives or Seq[primitive]

Tags: scala

How to create method, that will be accepting only primitives or their Seq's? Moreover it should be var-arg.

def method(args: Param*)

where args are for example

```
method(1: Int, 1l: Long, "1": String, Seq(1, 3, 7))
```

the second condition is that it can NOT accept value classes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define `Param` like this:

```
sealed abstract class Param

object Param {
  implicit final class IntParam(val x: Int) extends Param
  implicit final class StringParam(val x: String) extends Param
  ...
  implicit final class SeqParam(val seq: Seq[Param]) extends Param
}
```

Comment: One of the drawbacks is that in every place I use method I need to explicitly import Param._ 
Second problem is conversion. For every parameter there is created Param  wrapper instance and I must avoid unnecessary memory allocation

Comment: I'm looking for something at compiler level like declaring 
type Param = AnyVal or Seq[AnyVal]

Comment: You don't need to `import Param._`, because it's the companion object of `Param`. However, you do have the wrappers. I don't see a way around that.

Comment: @Przemek Using `AnyVal` as a constraint can't really work, because you can make any type of `AnyVal` that contains whatever you want.